# express.js exclude a path for html files?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars.js

I use handlebar as template engine, I have

```
app.engine('handlebars', exphbs({defaultLayout: 'layout'}));
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');
```

in my app.js.

Then later on, as usual I have route like

```
router.get('/dashboard', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('dashboard')
}
```

where I have `dashboard.hbs` in my view.

But what about if I want to use the path of `example.com` to serve one entire html files, like a html5 template? Can I not use handlebars? Because all the images and css are ready, I just need to upload them. But since I use template engine I feel like I'm tied to the templates of views.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just add a static route, as in

```
app.use(express.static('public'));
```

before the other routes, and add all your static files in the folder `/public`, you can serve up both `.html`, `.js` and `.css` files that are static, and all urls that don't match a static file, ends up in the router and your templates.

https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

Comment: Then you already have a route that handles all static files ?

Comment: I put a folder in my public called home and I have to go to localhost:3000/home which is not I want. I simply want localhost:3000 to serve my homepage, but I will be quite messed up if I put my css of my homepage together with my application. Anyway I can point/map localhost:3000 with localhost:3000/home?

Comment: No, that's the point, if your static route is `/public` that folder isn't visible, any static file in the root of `/public` would be access by `http://yoursite.com/static_file.html`, and then you'd add `css` and `js` folders *inside* of `/public` to do `http://yoursite.com/css/styles.css` etc.